# REST Lazy Reference Create GET or POST?

Tags: rest, lazy-initialization

I have a REST API where:

```
GET or POST /foo/{foo_id}/bar?a=1,b=2,c=3
```

and

```
GET /bar/{bar_id}
```

both yield

```
200 { bar_id: <GUID>, foo_id: <foo_id>, a: 1, b: 2, c:3 }
```

When no matching `bar` is found for the first call, `bar` will be generated and persisted. The operation is idempotent, but it is potentially not read-only. Should the first call be a `GET` or a `POST`? I am leaning towards both, because I can't find a convincing argument for one over the other in everything I have read on the subject.

Comment: I assume that you have default values for `a`, `b`, and `c`?  Without them, you wouldn't be able to use a GET as a creation mechanism.  If you want to follow the "standard" precisely, GET can only get a resource that already exists.

Comment: No defaults, but the parameters are required.

Comment: Ah, so `GET /bar/{bar_id}` when no resource exists still yields an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GET` should never create a resource. Not one that is visible to the user. It's a read-only operation.

The standard for both `POST` and `PUT` is to also return a [`201 Created`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) code, instead of `200 OK`, when a resource has been persisted. That is to completely distinguish whether a resource has been saved or simply retrieved.

You should ditch `GET` completely. If the first operation will always create a `bar` resource and will return a `409 Conflict` when a resource with the same identifier already exists, it's optimal if you used `POST`.

However, if you want to create a `bar` resource when a new one is passed or simply use an already existing one, you could even use `PUT` instead of `POST`. `PUT` is usually used for both creation and update of a resource, ie. it creates it when none-matching is found or updates it. But remember, `PUT` should be only used when you can update an entire resource during one request. For partial updates the `PATCH` method is much more suitable.

Comment: Fun fact: we only use POST in our API.  But it's not strictly a CRUD mechanism, so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I used to do quite the same, but recently found the `PUT` and `PATCH` methods quite fitting for several situations. Though `POST` is probably the most general one and can be used virtually for any resource creation.

Comment: I'm in, `GET` really is not appropriate. I'm starting to think the first API should be `POST /bar?foo_id={foo_id}&a={a}&b={b}&c={c}` and use 200/201 to discern if the `bar` was pre-existing or created.

Comment: There is no problem with GET creating a resource. But the client should not use GET to create a resource.

Answer (score 3):

> Should the first call be a GET or a POST?

It should be a `GET`.

The key reason is that the client, if I'm following correctly, **does not know it is creating a resource** nor is setting out to create a resource.

The client wants the current state of the resource from the server. It is not aware this might mean creating a resource and it does not care one jolt that this is the first time anyone has attempted to get this resource before, nor that the server has to create the resource on its end (what ever that means in the context of the server).

The client just wants the current state of that resource.

REST has nothing to do with CRUD operations on the server side. In fact the point of REST is that those details should be hidden from the client. The client doesn't care at all what the server has to do to manage to give the client a representation of the resource. If the server has to run a big SQL query in a transaction to create this resource, client doesn't care.

The thing to remember here is the direction of control. The client is saying to the server *give me* **your** *representation of resource `foobar`*. That is what GET is. how the server does that is up to the server.

If you used `POST` or `PUT` that is the client saying *"Here is* **my** *representation of `foobar`, update yourself"*

But in your scenario the client isn't responsible for the initial creation of `foobar`, the server is. The client just wants the server's representation and should be unaware of any side effects from that operation.

Comment: This was exactly my line of thought when I first created the API, but the rest of my team agree with @david-packer in that the write operation makes it a POST. I guess this is the grey area of not having a formal definition of REST. This page supports that GET is the correct method as it is both safe and idempotent: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/

Comment: Well luckily there is a formal definition of REST, it is Roy Fielding's [thesis](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) where he defined the term and the idea behind it. The problem is that in software development often the Big Idea gets lost as developers learn about ideas through a series of school playground Chinese Whispers. I would strongly recommend going to the source, the thesis is kinda heavy going but it grounds all other discussion of REST in terms of what the big concept Fielding is describing.